# how to filter Loop through an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a table, I try to put the data of the array into the table

for example:

```
var myArray = ["A","B","C","101","D","E","F","201","G","H","I","101"];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ; i++) {
     var newArray= myStringArray[i];
    //Do something
}
```

The following looks like

[image]

Now I want to display only table4=101, what can I do?

[image]

I try to put if inside for

```
var myArray = ["A","B","C","101","D","E","F","201","G","H","I","101"];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ; i++) {
     var newArray= myStringArray[i];
       if(table4.equals(101){
         //Do something
      }
}
```

But not working, I still got all the data.

How can I modify it?

Thank you

Comment: `myStringArray` is not shown to be defined in any of the snippets

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest that you convert your flat array into a 2-dimensional array, so instead of:

```
["A","B","C","101","D","E","F","201","G","H","I","101"];
```

we have:

```
[
    [ "A", "B", "C", "101" ],
    [ "D", "E", "F", "201" ],
    [ "G", "H", "I", "101" ]
];
```

This will make working with the array much easier.

We can easily convert between the two like this:

```
let array2d = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i += 4 /* this is the row length */) {
    array2d.push(myArray.slice(i, i + 4));
}
```

This will create are two-dimensional array.

Now, to filter by a certain value:

```
const onlyRowsMatching101 = array2d.filter(row => row[3] === "101");
```

More information on [`array filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to look after and reply the result later

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```js
    var result = [];    
    var myArray = [
    [ "A", "B", "C", "101" ],
    [ "D", "E", "F", "201" ],
    [ "G", "H", "I", "101" ]
   ]; 

    myArray.forEach(function (item) { 
       if(item[item.length-1] === '101')
           result.push(item);
    }); 
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you organize your data into smart data, you will have much more success with your code. imagine if your data looked like this:

```
var myArray = [
  { id: 1, tab1: "A", tab2: "B", tab3: "C", tab4: "101"},
  { id: 2, tab1: "D", tab2: "E", tab3: "F", tab4: "201"},
  { id: 3, tab1: "G", tab2: "H", tab3: "I", tab4: "101"}
];
```

you would have much more success displaying and manipulating it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to look after and reply the result later